# Error 1004, looked up other's questions and still can't resolve

Tags: excel, vba, range

This is the code. I've used "with sheets... set...", same error. Tried select range and then set = selection. Tried using other name, like Dim othername as range. In the last code line, I try to print as pdf, and the Editor paints that part yellow and shows the error 1004.

```
Public Sub imprimir()
    Dim nomedoarquivo As String
    Dim rng_print As Range
    
    Sheets("ORDEM DE COMPRAS").Activate
        Set rng_print = Range("B3:L45")
        
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
    nomedoarquivo = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OC-" & Range("L42").Value & "-" & Format(Now(), "mm/yy") & ".pdf"
    
    rng_print.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=nomedoarquivo, Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
        , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Format(Now(), "mm/yy")`: `/` in a filename looks suspect. Try changing to `-` or `_` for example.

Comment: oh my, that's true, trying

Comment: worked, that was the issue, thank you!